Can a monoid, considered as a one-object category, have categorial products?
Given a monoid $M$, can it have products as a one-object category? I.e., is it possible to have elements $p_1, p_2 \in M$, such that
$(\forall x,y\in M)( \exists! h \in M)(x = h\cdot p_1 \land y = h \cdot p_2)$. If $M$ is a group, it must be trivial to satisfy this condition (take $x = p_1$).
Update: As DanielSchepler mentions in a comment, cardinality constraints rule out any finite monoid, except for the trivial one. Commutativity is also incompatible with the condition.

How can you take $x=p_1$ when the condition is to hold for all $x$ yet $p_1$ and $p_2$ are fixed?

$M = { 0 }$ would be a trivial example.  I'm not sure if there are any other examples.  (Certainly, if $M$ is finite, then $M$ being in bijection with $M^2$ would imply $|M|^2 = |M|$, and $|M| \ge 1$ would then force $|M| = 1$.)

@Randall, I meant "instantiate the condition with $x = p_1$", which gives $(\forall y)(\exists ! h)(p_1 = h \cdot p_1 \land y = h \cdot p_1)$. Because $M$ is a group, this forces $h = e$, and $M = {e}$.

If $M$ is commutative, then also it's forced to be trivial: there exists unique $h$ such that $h p_1 = h p_2 = e$, so $h$ is a unit and $p_1 = p_2$ is its inverse.  But then if you have two distinct elements $x,y$, then it's impossible to have $h p_1 \ne h p_2$.

@DanielSchepler, thank you, I'll update the question.

Suppose $X$ is an object in a category $\mathcal{C}$ such that $X \cong X \times X$.
Then the full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ consisting of $X$ (and its endomorphisms) has binary products and is a one-object category as you require.
Furthermore, every one-object category with binary products arises in this way (trivially).
For example, consider $\mathbb{N}$ as a set.
As is well known, $\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.
Therefore the endomorphism monoid $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ considered as a one-object category has binary products.

I had just come up with pretty much the same example, with the details that if $p_1 : n \mapsto 2n$ and $p_2 : n \mapsto 2n+1$, then for each $f,g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ there exists a unique $h : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $h p_1 = f$ and $h p_2 = g$ which you construct as $h(n) = \begin{cases} f(n/2), & n \mathrm{~even}, \ g((n-1)/2), & n \mathrm{~odd}. \end{cases}$  At least, I think so.  (So I guess I actually used $\mathsf{Set}^{\operatorname{op}}$ and a well-known isomorphism $\mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{N}$.)

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

Post comments instead of answering and Martin gets on my case, post answers instead of commenting and then get downvoted. Is this what happened in the months and years I spent away?
